# how config spring mvc to fill parameter of @RequestMapping based on Jackson annotation?

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

Jackson annotation works in serializing an object but, it is not work to resolve a request parameters.

There is a class with a Jackson annotation as follow:

```
public class Role{
    @JsonProperty(
        value = "description", 
        defaultValue = "description", 
        required = false, 
        access = Access.READ_WRITE)
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty(
        value = "code_name", 
        defaultValue = "permission", 
        required = true, 
        access = Access.READ_WRITE)
    private String codeName;

    ...
}
```

As you can see property codeName is serialized as code_name in json or xml. For example getting a role is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Role getRole(@PathVariable id){
    ...
}
```

where the result is:

```
{
  "description": "..",
  "code_name": ".."
}
```

and this is my mvc config:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Now, suppose there is a request map as follow:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Role create(Role role) {
    ...
}
```

I fill a form with fields named description and code_name and send to the server. But, description is just set into the input role and the codeName is null.

By the way, it is ok if the form field name replace with codeName.

Comment: "the value is null in role" the one returned by create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "new", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public Role create(@RequestBody Role role) {
```

Comment: I send data as form-data, this one is decode role from body and json encoding.